# Input text taking value 12 characters after and cannot accept value null is showing in console

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function textCounter(field, cnt, maxlimit) {
  var cntfield = document.getElementById(cnt)
  if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
  // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
  else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

```html
<form class="post_form" action="trivia_page.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="trivia_text" id="post_text" onKeyDown="textCounter(this,280);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this,'length' ,280)">
            </textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="trivia_post" id="post_button" value="Post"></input>
  <input style="color:blue;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;display:block;border:none;" readonly type="text" id='length' name="length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="280">
  <hr>

</form>
```

The value starts at 268 for some reason in the input field and I am also getting a cannot accept value null in the console.

Comment: You're calling the same function on every keypress and keyup in the element; while you *can* do that, it seems like you're wasting CPU cycles; further you're calling the same function with different arguments in the two calls. First correct that, to make sure it actually represents your use-case.

Comment: Does `maxlength` accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using keydown/up events i think it's better to use the input event. Inputs can happen without pressing a button. After removing the whitespace of the textfield and binding your function to the input event it works fine.

I do recommend though to use Javascript to bind event handlers instead of inline.

```js
function textCounter(field, cnt, maxlimit) {
  var cntfield = document.getElementById(cnt)
  if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
  // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
  else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

```html
<form class="post_form" action="trivia_page.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="trivia_text" id="post_text" onInput="textCounter(this,'length' ,280)"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="trivia_post" id="post_button" value="Post">
  <input style="color:blue;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;display:block;border:none;" readonly type="text" id='length' name="length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="280">
  <hr>
</form>
```

Better way of doing it will be using the maxlength property of the input element so you don't have to trim it yourself and use javascript event binding. See example below.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('post_text').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    let el = e.currentTarget;
    let counterId = el.dataset.counter_id;
    let maxLength = el.maxLength
    let currentLength = el.value.length
    document.getElementById(counterId).value = maxLength - currentLength;
  });

  //Set the initial value of the counter by dispatching the input event manually as recommended by Anthony 
  document.getElementById('post_text').dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input"));
});
```

```html
<form class="post_form" action="trivia_page.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="trivia_text" id="post_text" maxlength="280" data-counter_id="length"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="trivia_post" id="post_button" value="Post">
  <input style="color:blue;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;display:block;border:none;" readonly type="text" id='length' name="length" size="3" maxlength="3">
  <hr>
</form>
```

Comment: Binding to the input event, I think you mean.

Comment: @Anthony Yes indeed. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: For `let maxLength = el.getAttribute('maxlength');` you can also use `el.maxLength` since it is a property on the TextAreaElement (but consistently using `getAttribute` makes sense too)

Comment: Oh but I really like the use of the data variable to tie the counter element to the textarea

Comment: @Anthony Yeah using the property is better, at least for readability. Both methods give the same result though.

Comment: All that's left is having the default (loading) value of the counter itself to be the maxLength without having to set `value="280"`

Comment: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('trivia_text').dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input"));
});`

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I did that in my 2nd snippet?

Comment: @Mark: I don't know how I missed that! My sincere apologies, and comment deleted.